# Pow-like function for negative base case

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, exponentiation

std::pow is fine for most combinations of base and exponent values.

However when the base is negative and fractional, std::pow keels over.

In the example below NaN is returned (as per definition), <strike>when the expected value is roughly: -1.2332863005546</strike>

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

int main()
{
    double a = -1.1;
    double b =  2.2;
    double c = std::pow(a,b);
    printf("%5.2f ^ %5.2f = %25.10f\n",a,b,c);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: Any ideas on how to develop a generic pow function that returns non-NaN values when the base is negative?

Update - There will always be a class of results that can only be expressed using complex numbers.

Comment: You need to decompose the exponent into a fraction, then use `pow` for power, root and `abs` if the base appears to be negative.

Comment: What do you expect this to mean mathematically? You need complex numbers.

Comment: Fractional power of negative number has several solutions in complex space...

Comment: The following seems to suggest there's some kind of answer in the real domain: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1.1%5E2.2

Comment: @Gerdiner http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1.1%29%5E2.2

Comment: @BoBTFish `(-1.1) ^ 2.2 = (-1.1) ^ (11 / 5) = fifthroot((-1.1) ^ 11) = fifthroot(-2.85311670611) = -1.23328630055`...

Comment: @robmayoff Right, added some parentheses.

Comment: @robmayoff Could you please elaborate as to why my answer is not correct with parens added?

Comment: @robmayoff Typo, sorry. Of course I meant "not correct"...

Comment: @H2CO3 I was mistaken.  Your number is a solution of (-1.1)^2.2, just not the principal solution.  I believe the solutions are (approximately) 0.99775+0.724907i, -0.381106+1.17292i, -1.23329, -0.381106-1.17292 i, and 0.99775-0.724907i.  http://wolfr.am/13fKB0J

Comment: @robmayoff Yes I was actually surprised that the math didn't work out, but apparently it was just that I wasn't paying enough attention. Thanks for the clarification and sorry for the noise.

Comment: As 2.2 is not typically exactly representable as a double, 5*2.2 may not be exactly 11, thus (-1.1) ^ (2.2*5) may instead result in a complex number near the real number -1.2332...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not the expected value. The expected value is the complex number `0.998 + 0.725i`. If you define `a` and `b` as `std::complex<double>` it will work.

Comment: No, this is the expected value. Or at least one of them. See my comment on the question.

Comment: You might want to refresh your knowledge on the power operation for negative bases.

Comment: To be more precise: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Real_exponents_with_negative_bases. Your solution dictates a different (non-conventional) choice of the complex logarithm.

Comment: Who cares when that's what OP wants?

Comment: @filmor, you're right. I should have passed (-1.1)^2.2 to wolfram. I've updated the question.

Comment: The OP gave this as an example for a "generic pow function", your method only works for fractional exponents and is only kind-of stable for "nice" ones (i.e. `p/q` with `p` and `q` small).

Comment: @filmor Yes, the first assertion ("only works for fractional exponents") is true, and it indeed is implied by the line about fractions in the answer. I think OP's point was rather the ability for using negative bases.

Comment: The point still stands, that your `decompose_fract` is highly non-trivial and the method of doing `a ** (b/c) = (a ** b)**(1/c)` is numerically very unstable.